# Tableview cell setting keep changed when I scroll down and get back swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a table view like this image(1). When the table view cell's text get "Cancel Schedule" or "Off day" the button ">" will be grey and the cell is unable to click.

my code is work but when I scroll down and get back, the setting will mess up. the setting will randomly change like the image(2) and (3). why?

Image(1): https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k6ldrfx5nzyt9e/1.jpg?dl=0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rosterId", for: indexPath) as! RosterCell
        ...
        if jobCancel[indexPath.section] == 0{
            cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            cell.jobDetail.textColor = UIColor.gray
            cell.button.isEnabled = false
            cell.button.alpha = 0.3;
        }
        if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancelled Schedule"{
            cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            cell.button.isEnabled = false
            cell.button.alpha = 0.3;
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        if cell.jobDetail.text == "Off Day"{
            cell.separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            cell.button.isEnabled = false
            cell.button.alpha = 0.3;
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

}
```

something like image(2) or image(3)

image(2): https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmile0vxpcqgt92/2.jpg?dl=0

image(3): https://www.dropbox.com/s/94ef4hb996afmm6/3.jpg?dl=0

Comment: When u go back and come to same cell , cell gets recreated , if you are making decision based on some property value in cell class be assured that property will be reinitialised , losing the value that you set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The reason for this is cell reuse.

It means cells that have already been styled in a certain way can be reused to display different data. You have to make sure that you setup every aspect of the styling each time a cell is reused to avoid cross over.

**It might be easier to keep track of the styling if you make a `configureCell` method to handle it, this way you can't forget to set one value and you could even set some default values.**

```
func configureCell(cell:RosterCell,
               textColour:UIColor,
               seperatorColour:UIColor,
               buttonEnabled:Bool,
               buttonAlpha:CGFloat,
               interactionEnabled:Bool = false) {

        cell.separator.backgroundColor = seperatorColour
        cell.jobDetail.textColor = textColour
        cell.button.isEnabled = buttonEnabled
        cell.button.alpha = buttonAlpha
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = interactionEnabled

}
```

Then your `cellForRowAt` method would look like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rosterId", for: indexPath) as! RosterCell
    ...
    if jobCancel[indexPath.section] == 0{
        configureCell(cell: cell,
                  textColour: UIColor.gray,
                  seperatorColour: UIColor.darkGray,
                  buttonEnabled: false,
                  buttonAlpha: 0.3,
                  interactionEnabled: true)
    }
    if cell.jobDetail.text == "Cancelled Schedule"{
        configureCell(cell: cell,
                  textColour: UIColor.gray,
                  seperatorColour: UIColor.red,
                  buttonEnabled: false,
                  buttonAlpha: 0.3)
    }
    if cell.jobDetail.text == "Off Day"{
        configureCell(cell: cell,
                  textColour: UIColor.gray,
                  seperatorColour: UIColor.darkGray,
                  buttonEnabled: false,
                  buttonAlpha: 0.3)
    }

}
```

As you can see I have set the `interactionEnabled` parameter to default to `false` so I did not need to set it for the last two if statements.